# Prove that Sy ≡ {x ∈ R : (x, y) ∈ S} is open for every y in R.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a question in real analysis that says: For $S ⊆ R^2$ define, for every $y ∈ R$, $S_y ≡ \{x ∈ R : (x, y) ∈ S\}$. Show that, if $S$ is open in $R^2$, then $S_y$ is open in $R$ for every $y ∈ R$.

I have been trying to prove this using open balls. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to prove the "projection" of your open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the x-axis is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider a point $x$ in this projection. It's there because there was a $(x,y) \in S$ that got projected to it. Now, $S$ is open, so you can find a ball of some radius $r$ contained in $S$ which contains $(x,y)$. How do you use this to find a 1-dimensional ball (open interval) contained in $Sy$ which covers $x$?

Comment: OK, what if I thought about S as being the cartesian product of two open sets, S1 and S2. Then S = S1 x S2 = { (x,y) : x ∈ S1 , y ∈ S2 }. If S can be defined as this, then is S1 basically the "projection?" If so, S1 is open, so we can find a ball around every x ∈ S1.

Comment: This would be possible if every open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ was the product of two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. they all look like boxes. But that's not the case even for a circular ball. There's a way to make this work, arguing that although it's not a product of two such sets, it can be obtained by an arbitrary union and finite intersection of those, but this could get complicated (see here if you're interested though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

For this particular problem, why not just take the interval $(x-r, x+r)$ and show every point in it is in $Sy$?

Comment: I can picture why this works; since S is open, we can find a ball around every (x,y)∈S.  This ball extends in both the x and y "directions" in R2, so it also extends in the x direction in R, where the projection is.  In R, this ball is (x−r,x+r).  I'm having trouble showing that every point in this interval is in Sy though, can you give another hint here?

Comment: That's it. The open ball around (x,y) of radius r contains the points $(x - e, x + e) $ for all $ 0 \leq e < r$, and there's a bijection between these and the interval.